# Map whose fibers are homotopic/homeomorphic are is a fibration

Tags: fiber-bundles, fibration

Now I know that the fibers of a fibration are homotopy equivalent, but I was wondering if the converse was true if we have the stronger conidition that the fibers are homeomorphic. If a map whose fibers are homeomorphic do we have a fibration, and if we weaken it to just homotopy equivalent are there additional conditions we can give so that the map is a fibration.

Comment: Suppose that X and Y are two topological spaces with the *same* underlying set, and such that the identity function $X\to Y$ is continuous. All fibers are homotopy equivalent, and in fact homeomorphic. Is it a fibration?

Comment: No, not neccesarily. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you delete the question?! It is certainly a useful question to have around.

Comment: I just wasn't sure if this was a good enough question for the site is all. I have undeleted.